# Load XML from Jenkins URL

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to load XML with Jenkins machines and their statuses.
When I'm passing content of XML in a variable the script works. Now my problem is to get the XML content from Jenkins URL.

I'm getting 2 errors:

- First:

  > "New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2"."
- Second:

  Using `Invoke-WebRequest` it always fails on HTTP status 403 with message:

  > "No valid crumb was included in the request"

  even though I provide it.

Here is my script:

```
$url = '<jenkinsURL>/computer/api/xml'
$usr = 'username'
$pwd = 'password'

$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $usr, $userPassword

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('Jenkins-Crumb','XXXXX')

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile "D:\file.xml" -Credential $userCredential -Method POST -Headers $headers
```

Comment: The credential creation works for me. What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: @Tomalak OP is using a secure string.

Comment: Your script seems fine to me. Should be a Jenkins problem. I am getting the same error.

Comment: See if this helps: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained

Comment: Thx for your comments, will keep trying. I have PS version: 5.1.14409.1012.

Comment: Did you actually [fetch a crumb](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection) first?

Comment: I did not fetch a crumb first, I got it manually for now, here https://<jenkinsURL>/crumbIssuer/api/xml

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some struggle, lots of reading, trials and failures, I finally figured it out and it works. Might be quite specific for our environment but hopefully will help someone. Now it seems quite simple and I don't know why my initial code did not work. Anyway, here it is:

```
$usr = 'username'
$pwd = 'password'
$url = "jenkins-url"

# --- get crumb ---
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$(${usr}):$(${pwd})")))
$getCrumb = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$url/crumbIssuer/api/json" -Method GET -Headers $headers
$crumb = $getCrumb.crumb

# --- get Jenkins XML
$headers.Add('Jenkins-Crumb',$crumb)
$xmlData = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url/computer/api/xml" -Method GET -Headers $headers | Select-Object *).Content
```